# Should I use SystemVerilog 2-state data type in design (not verification)?

Tags: system-verilog

SystemVerilog has 2-state data type, should I use it in design (not verification)?

I know it would improve the simulation performance but does it have any impacts on synthesis?

Answer (score 0):

Using 2-state does not necessarily improve simulation performance unless it can save you a significant amount of memory. Synthesis tools do not really care about 2-state versus 4-state unless you are specifying don't cares in either literals or parameters, not variables. So I would say it has no impact on performance.

The real issue about using 4-state versus 2-state is really in simulation and where you need or want to propagate X-values for error conditions or don't cares.